# How to create a layout dynamically using Json in android and get value from it ? Here is the Json

Tags: android, json, android-layout

```
{
  layout:[
   {
    tag :"edittext",
    name :"Name",
    hint :"Type your name here"
   },
   {
    tag :"checkbox",
    name :"Is married",
    hint :""
   },
   {
    tag :"button",
    name :"Submit",
    hint :""
   }
 ]
}
```

I am describing what exactly i want . First of all the above json will change every time. Structure will same , just tag, name and hint value will change . Now the above jsonarray has three jsonobject . it might be any number(4/5/6 any number of jsonobject) . Can any one plz suggest me how to solve this issue ? Thanks

Comment: What you want in your layout ?

Comment: How do you define the position of each view if u want it dynamically. In other case, I believe it is straight forward to create the views by loop parsing the json array and create views to the parent. It is a matter of parsing tag and create respective view with new constructor.Attach the same to the view

Comment: You must post your code, and ask for help.

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42366353/is-it-possible-to-set-xml-layout-as-a-view-not-from-resources-dynamically/42678791#42678791

Answer (score 1):

Its better to divide your question in small small parts, so here is something i have for your

1. **Parse JSON and fetch its value** : I suggest you to follow [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android) this link and you will have everything from your json.
2. **Check whether control is EditText or Button or anything else** : I will suggest you to use switch case for better coding structure

   ```
   switch (tag ){
       case "edittext":
           //add edittext
           break;
       case "button":
           //add button
           break;
   }
   ```

follow this links to add controls dynamically

[Generating Edit Text Programatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985825/generating-edit-text-programatically-in-android)
[Add button to a layout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907609/add-button-to-a-layout-programmatically)
[How to add checkboxes dynamically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618553/how-to-add-checkboxes-dynamically-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your layout according to the size of jsonarray.

```
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("layout");
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.statsviewlayout);

    for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
    {
        try {
            JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            // Pulling items from the array
            String tag = oneObject.getString("tag");
            String name= oneObject.getString("name");
            String hint= oneObject.getString("hint");
            Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setText(name);
            button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.addView(buyButton);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // Oops
        }
    }
```