# Is it possible to set xml layout as a view not from resources dynamically?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-resources

I want to set dynamic layout which is not present in resource like res or values.If it is present in my file-manager and i want to set that layout as a view layout.Is it possible to set dynamic layout to the views, without building app.I want to send the layout from the server and download the layout and set for the view without building and not from the resources.Is Butter knife used for this process or it's just for binding views to the variables.

Answer (score 2):

Try [**Proteus**](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus)

**Proteus** is meant to be a drop-in replacement for Android’s `LayoutInflater`; but unlike the compiled XML layouts bundled in the APK, Proteus inflates layouts at runtime.
With Proteus, you can control your Apps layout from the backend (no WebViews). Forget the boilerplate code to `findViewById`, cast it to a `TextView`, and then `setText()`. Proteus has runtime data bindings and formatters. Plugin in your own custom views and attributes and formatters.

p.s. large parts of [Flipart](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flipkart.android) is built using [proteus](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus)

Answer (score 0):

Butter knife used only for view binding.For this process you need fetch XML file from storage and then convert it into the view and then set as your layout.

Comment: Means it's possible like I will download my layout file locally and pass to the butterknife.so it will set dynamic layout, how it will set please give me one line of code to set the layout through butterknife without setContentView()

Comment: Butterknife doesn't set layout it bind layouts and listeners- http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: There is no inbuilt method for this. You need to fetch your XMl file and then convert it into view by your self.

Comment: Like this : 
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myName);
Button extra = new Button(this);
extra.setText("extra");
ll.addView(extra);

Comment: I understand to create custom view, but what I am telling is if my xml file is in file manager how i will inflate that xml file and add to the linear layout because that is not present in resources right? and is not builded to create     resources @Patel

Answer (score 0):

**No, you can't** send layout file from the server and inflate it dynamically. All views in Android have IDs mapped in R.java file. You can't and shouldn't modify it manually.

**Butterknife is used for View Binding** and help to reduce findViewById boilerplate. **You can't use Butterknife to add Views.**

However, you can dynamically create views using Java code and add them to any container layout. eg You can add a button to a Linear layout like this.

```
ViewGroup linearLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutID);

Button someButton = new Button(this);
someButton .setText("A Button");
someButton .setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linerLayout.addView(someButton );
```

Comment: Is there any library to do that or no library will do dynamic injection of layout?