# Addind CheckBox when click on Button

Tags: android, checkbox

i have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raB2X.png) layout

I need to create new CheckBox when i press the button. CheckBox should be the same like the previous ones. 
This is my CheckBox code:

```
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />
```

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618553/how-to-add-checkboxes-dynamically-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You should set onClick to this button:

```
  <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="ALO" />
```

.

```
public void ALO(View view) {

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.youridoflayout);
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        cb.setText("Hi there");
        ll.addView(cb);


    }
```